# How to convert Firestore DocumentSnapshot to dart object instance

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class as follows which i need to read/write to/from FireStore.

```
class Customer{
   String fname;
   String fname;

   Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'fname': fname,
    'lname': lname
  };

  static Customer fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc){
    Customer customer = Customer();
    customer.fname = doc.data['fname'];
    customer.lname = doc.data['lname'];
    return customer;
  }
}
```

How can I avoid writing code to serialize(toJson) /deserilize (fromDocument)? For amazon if i have to do this in java i would use Gson  library to serialize and deserialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) package, that generates code for serializing/deserializing. With it your code will look like that:

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
class Customer {
  Customer({this.fname, this.lname});

  final String fname;
  final String lname;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$CustomerToJson(this);

  static Customer fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$CustomerFromJson(json);
}
```